# How can I create an array of user-provided numbers and map that to an array of the numbers' cubes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My application is having a user supply a set of numbers. The user determines how many numbers they will provide, and then I prompt them accordingly. I want to create an array of the provided input numbers using a function. Then I want to use another function to calculate the cube of each of these numbers, and put those in a new array. I am finding it difficult to create the array of cubes. Can anyone help me with this?

```js
var BR = "<br />";
var ES = " ";
/********* FUNCTIONS *********/
// Enter any functions in this region

function fncube(c) {
    var result = 1;
    var tro;
    for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
        result = c[j] * c[j] * c[j];
        tro = new Array(result);
    }
    return tro;
}

function displayarray(d) {
    
    var mm = new Array();
    for (var m = 1; m < d.length; m++) {
        mm = mm.push[m];
        
    }
    return mm;
    
}

/********* MAIN *********/
function main() {
    
    var userinput = new Array();
    //var m = new Array();
    var usersize;
    var tilavg;
    
    usersize = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter number of cubes you would like to make: "));
    
    for (var i = 0; i < usersize; i++) {
        userinput[i] = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter your number #: " + (i + 1)));
        
        document.writeln(BR + "Number you entered " + " for making cube is : " + userinput[i] + ES)
        document.writeln(BR + "The cube is " + fncube(userinput) + ES);
        var cc = fncube(userinput);
        xx = new Array(cc);
        //var z = displayarray(cc);   
        
    }
    document.writeln(BR + "The array of input values is: " + cc);
    document.writeln(BR + "The array of cubes is: " + xx);
}
main();
```

Comment: How array of cubes different from any other array? How would you create an array of input numbers?

Comment: Thankyou for responding, this is the code I tried:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript Array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method natively supports transforming an array to another array of the same size where the translation function is the same for each element. If you define your transformation function as the cubing operation (in JS that's `Math.pow(x, 3)`), then you can easily translate from one array to another.

Consider the example below. I use jQuery's version of `map` to transform `input` elements to an array of their values, then use the JS `map` method to transform that array to an array containing the cubes of all the values. Give it a try. You should be able to tweak this to fit your use-case once you understand how `map` works.

```js
$(function() {
    $("input").change(function() {
        var nums = $("input").map(function() {
            return this.value || undefined;
        }).get();

        $("#nums").text(nums);
        $("#cubes").text(nums.map(function(i) {
            return Math.pow(i, 3);
        }));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Enter four numbers</h4>
<input /><br />
<input /><br />
<input /><br />
<input />
<div id="nums"></div>
<div id="cubes"></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou nbrooks! Would you be able to help with creating cubes using the for loop which does not use the math.powfunction ?

Comment: @staybnyc What's wrong with `Math.pow`? Anyway, cubes are pretty easy to compute: `Math.pow(i, 3)` is identical to `i * i * i` (just better looking).

Comment: its for an assignment, so we have to compute without the math.pow, ill try with i * i * i, thank you!

Comment: @staybnyc No problem! If this helped you solve your problem you should mark it as accepted to show that the issue was resolved, and help other folks find it in future (plus it gives a little credit to the person who answered).